# Young adult book series about three girls who had magical powers

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, witches

I read this book in the early 2000s.

It was a book about three girls, all in school, that had magical powers. One of them could read minds and was being pulled to dark magic. The other two girls could tell and started hiding their thoughts from her.

I remember it was part of a series, but can’t remember what it was called. Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you can recall any other details about the characters or plot, no matter how small, please [edit] your question to add them in. What you've described so far isn't much to go on.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

The *[Daughters of the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughters_of_the_Moon)* series by Lynne Ewing

> Vanessa, Catty, Serena, Tianna and Jimena seem like ordinary girls living in Los Angeles. But they each have a secret. Vanessa can become invisible, Catty travels back in time, Serena reads minds, and Jimena has premonitions and Tianna can do telekinesis. What separates them from others bands them together as Daughters of the Moon.

....

> Serena has long dark hair with red tips in the beginning of the series then she goes her natural dark brown. She has green eyes, and 3 piercings; one in her tongue, one in her nose, and one in her belly button. She is a Daughter of both Selene and Hekate resulting in her being a goddess of the moon and a goddess of the dark. She lives with her brother, Collin Killingsworth. Her best friend is Jimena, a fellow goddess. She stars in Into the Cold Fire (Book #2), and Possession (Book #8). She is the only Daughter to have the choice to become a goddess of the dark because she is the key to the balance of good or evil. She has the ability to read and cloud minds, powers similar to the Atrox's. She also has the ability to open and close portals. Serena continues to pursue an on and off relationship with Stanton, a Follower of the Atrox who later becomes the Prince of Night. Stanton is constantly worried because being with Serena can get them both killed by the Regulators. In the end, after she helps to defeat the Atrox, Serena has to make the choice of losing her memories of what she is and her powers, becoming a guardian spirit, or becoming the goddess of the dark. Stanton asks Serena to rule by his side and become the goddess of the dark and she accepts his offer. She stays in Nefandus with Stanton to make it a world of light.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the details described in the question?